# function for keypress event not triggered when typing too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L7bnzrz0/5/)

```
 var oldValue;

$(document).on('keydown','.main', function (e) {
    oldValue = $(this).val(); 
});
var newValue;
$(document).on('keyup', '.main',function (e) {
    newValue = $(this).val();
     foo(oldValue,newValue);
});

function foo(orig){
$('#table2').find('tbody tr').each(function (i) {
        var $td2 = $(this).find('td input:text');
        if (orig == $td2.val()) {
            $td2.val(newValue);
        }
    });
}
```

This is what happens,if I change "Apple" on table 1 slowly typing, "Apple" input field changes, but If I type too fast, my code is not working.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I am guessing, keydown/keyup are not fired in the correct order...

Comment: its function foo() that can't keep up. It gets triggered too fast. In another language, I would say, run the function on another thread, but JavaScript is singlethreaded.. 

Maybe look at AngularJS, with the bounded values? It's quiet easy, Or, you can throuw your find method away, give all fields id's, and try to do it that way..

Comment: @opatut Like this scenario, If I edit input field in the upper table and it does have duplicate on the lower table, it will automatically change value as to what Ive done edit on the upper table in keypress.

Comment: @KornelitoBenito, thanf for the info, do you have any suggestion, can I run foo function for this to work, for example,instead on keyup, it will trigger on button click?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.. But sure take a look at this example from w3schools: 

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro

Comment: To give your code every change of keeping up, (a) don't delegate the event handling, (b) avoid unnecessary DOM interaction in foo() - do as much as possible in javascript.

Comment: Besides, it's not clear, even with the demo, what the code is supposed to achieve.

Comment: @KornelitoBenito Javascript isn't singlethreaded, but either ways using web workers here wouldn't help, you would still have the same synchronization issues.

Comment: @Nit, the fact that web workers are available under HTML5 does not change the fundamental characteristics of JavaScript, which remains strictly single-threaded. A web worker can be regarded as a windowless, DOMless window running is own single-threaded instance of javascript. Thus, multiple threads are provided by the environment (the browser), not the language. And as you say, web workers won't help here anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

What if you add some relation between the original input-field and the corresponding like:

```
 <input type='text' class= 'main' value="Apple" rel="sec_apple"/>
```

and

```
<input type='text' value="Apple"  class="sec_apple"/>
```

for the second input.

Then you javascript could look like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.main',function (e) {
    foo($(this));
});

function foo(orig){
    rel = orig.attr('rel');    
    var sec = $('.' + rel);
    sec.val(orig.val());    
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hzgLgyh6/)**

Comment: Up for this, but this is in static way, like setting every rel for input,which I dont like it to be.Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Use JavaScript rather than jQuery. jQuery has a lot of overhead and can be too slow.

Probably not the case here.  You do need to  explain the issue a little better.

I ran a test and could not miss a key stroke, with my code.

My test routine changes the color of the background on each onkeyup.

I only used the two text inputs in table 1 to the right of Apple and banana.

Because I do not understand what you are doing, my test routine changes the color of the background on each onkeyup. If I type in 123456789 as fast as possible in both text fields they both come end with the correct color.

You may notice that I declare the inputs globally and use arrays instead of if else. Things that cannot be done efficiently with jQuery.

The reason I abandoned jQuery is I found jQuery to be way too slow on an iPad.

The following is tested at: [This test Location](http://ispeedlink.com/so/key/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"><head><title>keys</title></head><body>
Table1
<form id='form1'>
<table id='table1'><tbody>
<tr><td><input type='text' class= 'main' value="Apple"/></td>
<td><input id="t1" type='text' class= 'main' value="" onkeyup="key(1)"/></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><input type='text' class= 'main' value="Banana" /></td><td><input id="t2" type='text' value="" onkeyup="key(2)"/></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
Table2
<table id='table2'><tbody>
<tr><td><input type='text' value="Apple" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='text' value="Banana" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='text' value="Banana" /></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<br />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var color = new Array;
color[0] = '#f00';
color[1] = '#f0f';
color[2] = '#ff0';
color[3] = '#0ff';
var nc=[0,0,0];
var next = [1,2,3,0];
var txt=new Array;
txt[1] = document.getElementById('t1');
txt[2] = document.getElementById('t2');
function key(id){
nc[id] = next[nc[id]];
txt[id].style.background=color[nc[id]];
}
//]]></script></body></html>
```

Comment: Except jQuery would not be as efficient.  Too often jQuery is used for a single simple routine where JavaScript would easily do the job.  When an issue pops up jQuery makes it unnecessarily more complex.